# quicksort on JS

Tags: javascript, python, algorithm, sorting

i am reading a book about algorithms. A writer use python for example code. There is his quicksort below on python

```python
def quicksort(array):
  if len(array) < 2:
    # base case, arrays with 0 or 1 element are already "sorted"
    return array
  else:
    # recursive case
    pivot = array[0]
    # sub-array of all the elements less than the pivot
    less = [i for i in array[1:] if i <= pivot]
    # sub-array of all the elements greater than the pivot
    greater = [i for i in array[1:] if i > pivot]
    return quicksort(less) + [pivot] + quicksort(greater)

print(quicksort([10, 5, 2, 3])) //returns [2, 3, 5, 10]
```

I tried to write the same but on JS. There is my function below. But it doesn't work correctly

```js
function a (array){
    if (array.length<2){
            return array
    }
    else{
    const pivot = array.shift() 
    less = array.filter(value => value <= pivot);
    greater = array.filter(value => value > pivot);
    let answer = a(less).concat((pivot), a(greater));
    
    answer = answer.concat(a(greater));
    return  answer
    }      
}
console.log(a([[2, 3, 5, 10])) //returns [2, 3, 3, 5, 3, 3, 10, 3, 3]
```

I thought that the problem was in the variables, so I changed the code and return was correctly

```js
function a (array){
    if (array.length<2){
            return array
    }
    else{
    const pivot = array.shift() 
    less = array.filter(value => value <= pivot);
    let answer = a(less).concat(pivot);
    greater = array.filter(value => value > pivot);
    answer = answer.concat(a(greater));
    return  answer
    }      
}
console.log(a([[2, 3, 5, 10])) //returns [2, 3, 5, 10]
```

Could you help me what is wrong in my first example. Also I checked [book's  js code example on github](https://github.com/egonSchiele/grokking_algorithms/blob/master/04_quicksort/javascript/05_quicksort.js), but it is very similar to mine

Comment: `array.shift()` mutates the array. `array[0]` as used in the example code, doesn't.

Comment: Like Robin said, instead of using `array.shift()` which actually mutates the array, you can use `array[0]` or `array.substr(0, 1)`

That way, I think it should work

Comment: Thanks. I used array.shift() to return number and delete it from array. I changed array.shift->array[0] and array.filter(....)-> array.slice(1).filter(..) but return is the same. I guess there is problem next line
```let answer = a(less).concat((pivot), a(greater));```
As if the variable ``greater`` changes in recursion ``a(less)``